# idiORM count() issue

Tags: php, orm, idiorm

I'm running into an issue using the idiORM class. (documentation found here: http://idiorm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

I'm trying to get the count of a certain query while keeping the original query for further processing, so I simply copied the original query into a second variable but it seems that as soon as I execute the `count()` method he copies everything to the other variable.

For example I create a query and save the returned ORM object into a variable `$ormResults`  and copy it into `$copy`:

```
$ormResults = ORM::for_table('department')->where('company', '4');
$this->_orginalResults = $ormResults;

// Copy the ORM object into $copy
$copy = $ormResults;
$this->resultCount = $copy->count();
```

Up until here it works fine, the expected count result is correctly stored in `$this->resultCount`. However when I now var dump the (up until now) unused variable `$this->_orginalResults` it also contains the `count()` properties which baffles me as I have not used it at all.

```
protected '_resultColumns' => 
array
  0 => string 'COUNT(*) AS `count`' (length=19)
```

Which causes trouble when I try to execute `$this->_originalResults->findMany();`.
Is this because the `count()` method returns the ORM object? As far as I know PHP code doesn't travel upwards.. does it?

So Tl;dr:

```
$test = ORM::forTable('departments')->where('company', '8');
$test2 = $test;
// Works
var_dump($test->count());

// Fails
var_dump($test2->findMany());
```

However this works perfectly fine:

```
$test = ORM::forTable('departments')->where('company', '8');
$test2 = ORM::forTable('departments')->where('company', '8');

var_dump($test->count());
var_dump($test2->findMany());
```

Any insight / help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok figured it out, apparantely some of the static variables are ruining it.

using `clone` to copy the object works perfectly.

```
$test = ORM::forTable('departments')->where('company', '8');
$test2 = clone $test;

 var_dump($test->count());
 var_dump($test2->findMany());
```

Does the trick